# Use JavaScript function return statement to open a new page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a webpage that uses Adyen Encryption for Credit Cards. I have a form in which I ask for Credit Card data, and when the user presses `submit` it calls the JavaScript function. Now I want to redirect that page into another one that shows the value returned with the JavaScript function. I don't know if there is a simple way to do it.

The **index.html** code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://my.tidal.com/assets/javascripts/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://my.tidal.com/assets/javascripts/payment/adyen.js"></script>
    <script src="https://my.tidal.com/assets/javascripts/payment/brazil-validate.js"></script>

    <script>
        function test(name, card, expMonth, expYear, cvc) {     

            var adyenPubKey = "10001|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

            var options = {};

            var cseInstance = adyen.encrypt.createEncryption(adyenPubKey, options);

            var generationTime = new Date().toISOString();  

            var cardData = {
                number : card,
                cvc : cvc,
                holderName : name,
                expiryMonth : expMonth,
                expiryYear : (expYear.length === 2) ? '20' + expYear : expYear,
                generationtime : generationTime
            };

            return cseInstance.encrypt(cardData);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form onsubmit="return test(document.getElementById('holderName').value,document.getElementById('number').value,document.getElementById('expiryMonth').value,document.getElementById('expiryYear').value,document.getElementById('cvc').value)" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="holderName" id="holderName" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" id="number" pattern="[0-9]{16}" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" id="expiryMonth" pattern="[0-9]{2}" required>
        <input type="text" id="expiryYear" pattern="[0-9]{4}" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" id="cvc" pattern="[0-9]{3}" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: IF THE SECURITY IS NOT YOUR CASE, YOU CAN USE `WINDOW.LOACATION` BY PASSING PARAMETERS AS QUERY STRINGS.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour would you mind not using CAPS please? It's considered as you yelling. That notion has been around since near the beginning of the public Internet. References:  https://newrepublic.com/article/117390/netiquette-capitalization-how-caps-became-code-yelling --- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps

Comment: I notice you're using a form and with a POST method. Where is the possible php for this and why wasn't this tagged as such? how is this being handled in regards to the processing of the form data?

Comment: **WARNING** I'm hoping that the `adyenPubKey` key isn't a real one here. If it is, you had better go and delete it now and create a new one.

Comment: *"Now I want to redirect that page into another one that shows the value returned with the JavaScript function."* - You need to pass that on to a language code that can process that data or a header, either with PHP or JSP. The question IMHO, is unclear (for me).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your particular use case - but if you want to redirect to a new page (or request a new page from the server) and have any information carry forward to the new page - you have to send the data to the server. The server can then send back only the particular information you want to show. (Just make sure to use HTTPS considering the nature of the data).

If this is a single-page application then you could simply hide the form and load the next 'screen' on the current page. This way you could re-use the in-memory result from your form. Just store it in an accessibly-scoped variable.

Another option may be to use local storage, but considering this is sensitive credit card information I would advise against this - encrypted or not.